# Ubuntu 18.04: Calibre in combination with Sony PRS-2 ereader stopped working

Tags: 18.04, sony, epub

my wife has a PRS2 eReader that worked with Calibre (latest version) on Ubuntu 16.04 as a charm.

I've recently updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and now Calibre cannot update the eReader anymore. The notification in Calibre is (some repetition deleted):

```
calibre, version 3.33.1
FOUT: Fout: Fout bij communicatie met apparaat
```

The SONY database is corrupted.  Delete the file `/media/natalia/READER1/Sony_Reader/database/books.db` on your reader and then disconnect - reconnect it. If you are using an SD card, you  should delete the file on the card as well. Note that deleting this file will cause your reader to forget any notes/highlights, etc.

The underlying error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "site-packages/calibre/devices/prst1/driver.py", line 296, in remove_orphaned_records
>   OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database*

So, after checking with the FileManager, I've indeed found that the disk from the eReader is read-only.
Then I remounted the disk using the command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/natalia/READER1
```

and could delete the file.

I've stopped the eReader, connected it again, of course an empty database, but again the same error. Even after a restart of Ubuntu itself.

Any ideas what has changed from 16.04 to 18.04 to get this behavior?
And do you have any suggestions what I can do to fix this?